# Why won't T-SQL Stored Procedure return from SYS.DATABASE_PRINCIPALS

Tags: database, t-sql, stored-procedures, permissions

```
Create procedure test.access
      @principal_id int
      with execute as owner
      as
      set nocount on;
         begin
            select * from sys.database_principals where principal_id = @principal_id
         end;
```

I create the above procedure and execute but it returns nothing.  However if I declare @principal_id as a variable, set it then run this code outside a procedure it returns the correct rows.

Why isn't it working inside the procedure?

Comment: Your procedure [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=09d99c92ee5c2ce787c1c805425376a6) there must be something you're not telling us.

Comment: @Stu It works fine in dbfiddle because when you created the `test` schema it was owned by you, and in dbfiddle you have elevated privileges (so you can do things!)

Comment: @allmhuran yes absolutely, but is there any scenario where another user would never see any rows eg public role? I would have hoped the OP would have tested passing various values to narrow it down, doing so would surely have revealed it's not just the act of running a query in a procedure but the user/session running it...?

Comment: @Stu Yes, because the proc created by OP takes a `@principal_id` argument. If that argument has the value associated with a user/role that the owner cannot see, then the proc won't return anything.

Comment: The @principal_id I sent was my own and I'm an administrator anyway.  In my environment it's returning null.  But if I pull the parts out and run it just as myself I can see everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the owner of the test schema does not have elevated permissions, then the rows that can be seen in `sys.database_principals` will be limited. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Any user can see their own user name, the system users, and the fixed database roles. To see other users, requires ALTER ANY USER, or a permission on the user. To see user-defined roles, requires ALTER ANY ROLE, or membership in the role.

In the following script I create the user `test`, as well as a schema `test`. I make the `test` user the owner of the `test` schema.

I then create a procedure in that schema with `execute as owner`. It will therefore execute in the context of the `test` user.

But the `test` user does not have `ALTER ANY USER` permission, so the rows visible in `sys.database_principals` are limited:

```sql
create login test with password = 'test';
create user test for login test;
go

create schema test authorization test;
go

create procedure test.access with execute as owner as 
begin   
   select * from sys.database_principals;
end
go

exec test.access; -- returns a limited set principals
```

If I grant the `test` user the `alter any user` permission and then re-execute the procedure, I will get all of the users:

```sql
grant alter any user to test;

exec test.access; -- returns all users (but not user defined roles)

grant alter any role to test;

exec test.access; -- returns everyone and all roles
```

If the `test` schema is currently not owned by the correct user, you can change that:

```sql
alter authorization on schema::test to [user];
```

Comment: So just to clarify, I am database admin.  Wouldn't I already have the highest permission level?  And why can I see every row but the procedure I own cannot?

Comment: @PhillipHamilton Who you are when you run the procedure doesn't matter because of the `execute as owner` line. What matters is who owns the `test` schema. In my example the `test` schema is owned by the `test` user, and so the procedure uses the permissions of the `test` user.  You can see who owns the `test` schema with the query: `select user_name(principal_id) from sys.schemas where name = 'test'`

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try.  I created this schema and assumed I owned it but we were doing some work a while back assigning ownership so maybe the schema was accidentally given to a user without admin privileges.

Comment: @PhillipHamilton Right, being a sysadmin does mean you can do anything you like, but it doesn't mean you "own" all schemas. And that's often desirable, it's not universally true that everybody wants all of their schemas to be owned by a member of db_owner or sysadmin, for reasons exactly like this - it provides another level of granularity for controlling permissions, allows you to deliberately cut ownership chaining, etc etc.

Comment: This is what happened. I created the schema but in later work ownership was passed to a more restricted user for access.  But I was under the impression I still owned it.  Thanks for the help.